# What is a good strategy for quickly earning money in Plants vs. Zombies?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

I'm trying to collect all the achievements in *Plants vs. Zombies* on the iPhone. I need lots of money to buy all the plants, so I've been trying to work out a way to basically farm some money in the game. I've tried using Marigolds and the Magnet with a bunch of Tall-Nuts to slow the last few zombies down considerably, but the Marigolds only spawn money a few times before stopping.

What is a good strategy for quickly earning money in *Plants vs. Zombies*?

Comment: I edited the title to highlight the iPhone, a lot of good stragegy involve the Zen Garden or the survival, which do not exist on iphone according to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3156/how-does-plants-vs-zombies-differ-from-platform-to-platform

Comment: @Brett Could you put "iPhone" back in the title? There are  differences between the versions, so it would be good to make it clear. The same question about the PC GOTY version would not be a duplicate of this.

Comment: I'll recommend playing last stand mini-game with [this strategy](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mAXrw.jpg). It gives about $7,000  in just one play of 5 full flags .

Comment: I'd get some chocolate for your snail in the Zen Garden and let him do the grinding for you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For the iPhone version, I recommend using Marigolds on Lvl 1.1 (only the base zombie)

Basically you want to set up 3 lanes of marigolds with a single garlic at the front to divert the zombie into the other 2 lanes.

I hope this unicode art makes sense

```
┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐  
│S│M│M│M│M│M│M│M│G│ ← Z
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤   
│P│T│W│ │ │ │ │ │ │ ← Z 
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤    
│S│X│M│M│M│X│M│M│G│ ← Z
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤   
│P│T│W│ │ │ │ │ │ │ ← Z
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤   
│S│M│M│M│M│M│M│M│G│ ← Z
└─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
```

Legend:

- S = Sunflower/TwinSunflower
- M = Marigold
- P = Peashooter
- G = Garlic
- X = Gold Magnet shrooms
- T = Tallnuts
- W = Spikeweeds

The idea is to slow down how you kill the zombies. So as quickly as possibly, place the garlics to direct the zombies into the two lanes that are protected. After the initial setup, it's just a matter of placing the marigolds as quickly as possibly.

EDIT: I should have said that you place the gold magnet shrooms so that you get automatic coin collection; having two means less chance of a miss.

Comment: ASCII art for the win!

Comment: Unicode art > ASCII art

Comment: You have P in there twice (Peashooter/Spikeweeds). Which is which?

Comment: @Pitts: Wouldn't it be better to fill all the line 2 and line 4 with W?

Comment: Delete the peashooters after you get tallnut and spikes. Add a second tallnut where the peashooter was and add spikes when they break thru the first tall nut. This slows it down even further.

Comment: Not all W, but enough to kill the zombies then marigolds after that

Answer (score 2):

If you have not already, complete each puzzle at least once. The first time you finish each puzzle [on the PC version](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3156/how-does-plants-vs-zombies-differ-from-platform-to-platform), you're rewarded with a gem. The rewards for subsequent completions are usually (randomly) not as much, but still something. So if you find a puzzle you're quite good at, you might try beating it repeatedly.

Answer (score 2):

As an improvement to Alastair's answer, towards the end of the game, when there's only 1 zombie left, get rid of all the spikerocks and peashooters and replace them with Marigolds.  This way, the zombie won't die, and if you have Wall-nut first aid, you could just keep repairing the tallnut, allowing for potentially unlimited gold mining time.

Answer (score 1):

I usually just do wall-nut bowling under Quick Play.  If you can hit multiple zombies with a single wall-nut, you get bonus coins (one for the second zombie, two for the third, etc.)

Because you're on the iPod, you can't use the PC's survival or last stand for gold farming, and farming marigolds on 1.1 is too tedious for my taste (especially since, as you said, marigolds keep running out of money and have to be replanted).

Answer (score 0):

Go to survival level's  put a lot of big nutz to stop the zombies and something effective for killing it ... but not killing fast. Then put a lot of money flowers, maybe a gold magnet and ... it's up to you baby.

Comment: Do this, but play something, wait until the last zombie, then just keep throwing down tallnuts in front of it and collecting the money flower.

Comment: @Sam152: Great idea! I like that!

Comment: You could keep pat patching up the nuts for a endless barricade

Answer (score 0):

After completing adventure mode once, do adventure 2 and get to fog level 10 where there is the yeti zombie if you manage to kill him he gives you 4000 dollars (he will give you 5000 the first time you kill him).