# How does Plants vs. Zombies differ from platform to platform?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies, version-differences

*Plants vs. Zombies* is available for PC, iPad, and iPhone so far as I know. I'd like to help answer *Plants vs. Zombies* questions, but my knowledge is based on the PC version. So...

What platforms are *Plants vs. Zombies* available on?

Are there any major differences between the versions available on each platform such as: gameplay, campaign, puzzles, survival, achievements, or anything else?

Comment: Actually, I researched this same question a while back when I heard about the iPad version's "HD graphics". It turns out that because the iPhone version was a stripped-down version of the PC version, it looked pretty bad compared to it, so the "HD graphics" of the iPad version just make it look more like the PC version; that is, it's *not better* than the PC version.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since you are already familiar with the PC version, I'll go into the other ones:

#### iPhone version

It contains the entire campaign, as well as different achievements (also different Easter eggs, such as what happen if you scroll down the achievement listing continuously).  The puzzles are mainly the same as well.

- Doesn't have survival mode.
- Doesn't come with most of the bonus games (including the plant garden, the tree of wisdom, as well as the Zombiequarium minigame)

  - These must be purchased with either in-game coins or with real money using microtransactions
  - All Mini-game packs can be purchased for 50,000 coins each, the I, Zombie game pack for 150,000 coins, the Vasebreaker game pack for 150,000 coins, and the Last Stand game pack for 100,000 coins.

#### iPad version

Identical to the iPhone version, except it now includes the Survival mode.  However, now it includes a new way to improve the power of your cobb plants (by putting butter on enemies first).  This is making use of the iPad multitouch mode of up to 11 touches at once (think launching multiple walnut in walnut bowling at once).  Still no zen garden.

Read more on the Wiki here: [Game versions of Plants vs. Zombies](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Game_versions_of_Plants_vs._Zombies#)

Comment: There is also a mac version of the game, which seems to be a simple port of the PC version.

Comment: There is now an android version too.

Comment: PvZ for iPhone now features the Zen Garden, plus several bonus games: ZomBotany, Zombiequarium, It's Raining Seeds, Column Like You See 'Em, Slot Machine, Beghouled and Portal Combat.

Comment: There's also a version for the Nintendo DS. I don't have my DS with me so I can't give a full run-down on it, but I'll give a recap on it when I get home today.

Comment: There is also a version for the ps3 that includes a two player co-op mode. This mode also allows both players to 'butter' a zombie, practically delaying it indefinitly.

Comment: I have updated this answer to correct some incorrect points; I did not add in information about other game versions that also exist, as that would be putting words in the OPs mouth. Some of the other answers go into more detail below.

Answer (score 15):

According to the [Wikipedia article on *PvZ*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plants_vs._Zombies) and [the official *PvZ* site](http://www.popcap.com/games/plants-vs-zombies/) it is currently available for:

- Google Chrome (via Chrome Web Store)
- Microsoft Windows
- macOS
- iOS (iPhone, iPad, iPod Touch)
- Xbox Live Arcade
- Xbox 360 (Part of a PopCap compilation disc)
- PlayStation Network
- Nintendo DS
- Nintendo DSiWare
- Bada
- Android
- Windows Phone
- PlayStation Vita
- BlackBerry Tablet OS
- Kindle Fire

So pretty much everything under the sun at this point. And as new platforms become available, I expect to see it ported to those too.

As to version differences, from what I've seen the main campaign is mostly identical, the main differences seem to be the extras included with each version.

The [*Plants vs. Zombies* Fandom](http://plantsvszombies.fandom.com/) has a page about the [differences between platforms and langauges](http://plantsvszombies.fandom.com/wiki/Game_Versions) that is worth looking at.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. BTW, I'm pretty sure the Kindle Fire's version is just the Android version

Comment: @JohnoBoy The _PvZ_ site made a point mentioning the Kindle Fire version. Not being a Kindle user, I couldn't tell you what OS it runs off hand.

Comment: @JohnoBoy Ah, it is thru the Amazon App Store for Android.

Comment: the vita has an option to collect all the suns/coins on the field with a single tilt, making that part super easy.

Answer (score 7):

The [XBLA](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Plants-vs-Zombies/66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d802584109ff) version that came out in September also features coop mode, as well as:

- A goofy new way to track and share progress online, where players create their own custom house and cruise down the street to see their friends' cribs!
- The highest resolution of any Plants vs. Zombies adaptation to date at 1920 x 1080

*([source1](http://kotaku.com/5590065/co+op-and-versus-coming-to-360-plants-vs-zombies), [source2](http://kotaku.com/5590950/plants-vs-zombies-shambles-to-xbox-360-this-fall))*

Answer (score 4):

Plants vs Zombies is available for the following:

- PlayStation 3 (also works on Vita)
- Xbox Live Marketplace
- PC
- Android
- Windows Phone
- Iphone (and Ipad, Ipod touch)
- DSiWare (Nintendo DSI, 3DS)
- Nintendo DS

The game is similar version to version, though appears to run smoothest on PC, PS3, and Xbox 360. I would generally not recommend Popcap games on Nintendo platforms (usually poor frame rate).

Answer (score 3):

The PS3 version, which is released just few days ago in US(and might also in EU but not in Asia), looks like have identical features as the XBox's version but not yet explored.

The last time I played it is on PC(bought from Steam) for more than a year now, when I play it last night on PS3 I was disappointed with the new dancing zombie; I prefer the old one. Haven't had a chance to look at my pc version though 'coz my laptop is still broken. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Achievements also differ between versions — the Steam version has different achievements from the iOS version, which again differs from the console versions. The console versions have very few achievements.

Here's a [list of achievements](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Achievements) for the different platforms.

Answer (score 2):

It has also been announced that there will be a NDS version coming soon with "bonus features".