# What are the differences between Normal edition and the GotY (Game of the Year) edition?

Tags: pc, version-differences, plants-vs-zombies

All that I can find is the Zomvatar (zombie avatar) maker. Are there other differences between the editions?

Comment: Are you talking PC version or Xbox version? I would like to know the difference between the three anyways.

Comment: This seems like it should be community wiki, so the community can build one complete answer.

Comment: I've update my question and add PC tag

Comment: Next time please use just one meaningful tag, there was no need for the plants-vs-zombies series tag.

Comment: @TrickyM66 How does Plants vs. Zombies differ from platform to platform? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/3156/

Comment: @Cristina Sure I will. As I know, on stackoverflow.com site, there' s a feature that automactically merge `defined to be synonyms` tags  into one tag. Is it available with this SE siter gaming site?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some that I know of:

- New achievements
- Steam Cloud support for those on Steam
- The dancer zombie no longer looks like Michael Jackson

Comment: What is Steam (sorry to be very newbie)?

Comment: Steam is Valve Software's online game purchase/play network. Google "Valve Steam" ...

Comment: http://store.steampowered.com/ Simplest explaination: Like an iPhone's Apps store, but for the PC and limited to games. There is an install link at the top right of the page I linked to.

Comment: The Michael Jackson was removed from all versions of the game.

Answer (score 3):

Blurb when the GOTY edition was [released on Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/news/4183/):

> Plants vs. Zombies: GOTY Edition is now available with updated and expanded content including 20 new Steam Achievements, Steam Cloud support, and the interactive Zombatar™. Now with SteamPlay, Plants vs. Zombies can be played on either Mac or PC!

New info that other answers have not included:

- Now playable on Mac if bought through steam. I presume this was not possible before?

Also note, I purchased the normal version of the game on Steam, and I believe I received a free upgrade to the GOTY edition when it came out. Steam appears to only offer the GOTY edition now, since I can't [find the old version in the steam store](http://store.steampowered.com/search/?term=plants+vs+zombies). Good-bye Michael Jackson Zombie. ;(

Comment: Yes, Steam upgraded the old version to GOTY... they share the same appId on Steam, so unfortunately, the old version is gone for good.

Answer (score -2):

There are also new areas,zombos battles and new plants!

Comment: I don't play PvZ1 or 2 but I do watch videos on YouTube. Captain Hack is my favorite!

Comment: Could you elaborate on these new things? This is a bit vague and I'm not sure these new things are different than what others have described in their answers.